# MySQL - 3 columns of data. Need Count of data common to all 3 columns, and the data itself

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of 3 columns x,y,z. The rows contain data. Sometimes the value of the data is repeated.

Need to know which data is repeated and the count.
This simplified example has only a few values for the data.

In actuality, the table has several other columns and a primary key, and often there is no
data in x,y,z. The query would be called via php.

Table:

```
x y z
a
  b 
    c
  a d
    a
a b a
```

Desired MySQL Query result:

```
Data Count
a    5 
b    2
c    1
d    1
```

If anyone can help it would much appreciated. Have been fighting with this for several hours now and got nowhere fast.

Cheers,

Peter

Comment: I think the only way you can do that, is by iterating through the table results and count the stuff in an associative array, with the values as key.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT   a.data,
         COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     (
         SELECT x AS data FROM tbl WHERE x IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
         SELECT y         FROM tbl WHERE y IS NOT NULL UNION ALL
         SELECT z         FROM tbl WHERE z IS NOT NULL
         ) a
GROUP BY a.data
```

This gets the values from all three columns into one, so that it then becomes a simple `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`.